# SLAB stops receiving events from Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, etw, semantic-logging, slab

I have a Windows Service (`myService`) writing ETW events. When I start the service I'm able to see the logs written to file when SLAB Service (`slabService`) listens to the events.

After a few days `slabService` stops writing events. I don't think SLAB had stopped listening because if I restart `myService` **without** restarting `slabService` I can see the events flowing again into the file configured in the `slabService`.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start doing these two checks:

- Check SLAB internal logs and see if there is something interesting for the diagnostic.
- Use another ETW client (PerfView is an option) and check if it's perceiving the events.